# Does twisted.internet.serialport 17.1.0 work on Windows?

Tags: pyserial, pywin32, twisted.internet

I am trying to use twisted.internet.serial on Windows and it always fails to create with the message :

"File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet_win32seria
lport.py", line 65, in _finishPortSetup
    flags, comstat = win32file.ClearCommError(self._serial.hComPort)
AttributeError: 'Serial' object has no attribute 'hComPort'"

I have tried on Windows 10 x64 as well as Windows 7 x64, running as administrator, with Python 3.6.1 and Python 2.7.13.

I have installed twisted 17.1.0, PySerial 3.3, pywin32 221.

It appears to me that PySerial has been revised at some point to privatize the com port handle as self._port_handle rather than self.hComPort which twisted is expecting.

Is this a known issue? Is there a work-around? Are twisted and/or PySerial being improved w/r/t this issue?

Thanks, Dick

Comment: I found [link](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/8159) bug report from 16 months ago.

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question, I have discovered that this issue has been known for over a year. See https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/8159 .

There is a work-around: it is patch #2 which can be found at the link above.

No word yet as to whether the twisted folks has put any priority on releasing this patch into the mainline.

Answer (score 1):

While Twisted is not updated to use newer PySerial versions, I have resolved this by downgrading PySerial to `'pyserial<3.0'` (which installs `pyserial==2.7`).

```
pip install pyserial<3.0
```